# Android EditText on text change listener displaying many Toast messages when calling it on afterTextChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toast

I've a registration form activity in android, in which I want to display Toast message after completion of text field etName. Problem is it is displaying toast message as I go on editing the field, I want to display only one toast message that too after writing whole name. Below is the code.

```
    etName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi, "+ etName.getText().toString() +" !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `afterTextChanged` method is invoked after every change in edittext so basicly after every entered letter

Comment: No. It is registration activity for new user. If I knew the name already I'd count the complete string and then would've plotted the condition.

Comment: @karolZyglowicz: Ok, so is there any alternative for that method or any other way of doing it?

Comment: you should write your Toast on lost focus event of the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use like this:

```
etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi, "+ etName.getText().toString() +" !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be more suitable

```
etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi, "+ etName.getText().toString() +" !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```